# Can I do transfer between portfolios with withdraw and deposit APIs? [coinbase-api]

Tags: coinbase-api

We cannot use the following APIs to do transfer between portfolios.

1. “POST /withdrawals/coinbase-account" (url:https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/withdrawals/coinbase-account)
2. “POST /deposits/coinbase-account”   (url:https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/deposit/coinbase-account)

The error msg is as follows:
ApiError(status 403 code=): Invalid scope COINBASE args({'data': '{"amount": 0.1, "currency": "BTC", "coinbase_account_id": "4b08d5e5-fe77-4249-b017-301e8890652a"}', 'headers': {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'CB-ACCESS-KEY': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': '1594280190.878908', 'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'}, 'timeout': 30.0})

Let us know if these 2 APIs are for transfer between portfolios or not. However, if the API is ok, could you please demonstrate on the url and request payload for the following 2 use cases:

1. If I want to do transfer from profile A to profile B, using A's API keys(with transfer access) and A.withdrawals(asset, amount, coinbase_id = B)
2. If I want to do transfer from profile B to profile A, using A's API keys(with transfer access) and A.deposits(asset, amount, coinbase_id = B)

Especially, Does the coinbase_id stands for profile(potfolio) id or account(asset) id? How to obtain this id by API?

Comment: These are multiple questions at once, some of which really seem to be a matter of reading the documentation of the API in question.

Comment: it seems like the API documentation doesnt quite cover how to transfer using withdraw and trasnfer APIs.

Answer (score 1):

It's already a long time thread, I imagine you already found your answer but if not and for those interested, you can use the [`/profiles/transfer`](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#create-profile-transfer) route to transfer funds between your Coinbase Pro portfolios.

Just you must have an API key created from the "from" portfolio with the transfer permission.

Example:

```
POST /profiles/transfer
{
    "from": "86602c68-306a-4500-ac73-4ce56a91d83c",
    "to": "e87429d3-f0a7-4f28-8dff-8dd93d383de1",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": "100.00"
}
```

Comment: I have an API key created with transfer permission but I am not able to transfer funds.  Anything else I need to know?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain an account ID via obtaining an Oauth2 authorization first.  Once that is obtained you can use a Coinbase API (NOT PRO) call to obtain an account ID.  I will not cover the Oauth2 calls since they are decently documented. The API call using PHP CURL is as follows:

```
//////////////////////
// IMPORTANT, not covered how to obtain this

// Assuming a variable which contains the Oauth2 access code is passed in 
// with a variable name called 

// $oauth_provided_access_token
// IMPORTANT
//////////////////////

// Obtain Timestamp
$API_VERSION = '2021-02-26';
$timestamp = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/time"), true)["data"]["epoch"];

// Define request
$req = "/v2/user";

// Define full URL, why Coinbase cannot parse this and obtain the request is strange
$url = "https://api.coinbase.com" . $req;

// Obtain API key/Secret (Do not put this in your PHP code, obtain it via environment variables
// Note that the key and secret are not required in this instance
// but many Coinbase API calls will need them

//$key    = $_SERVER["HTTP_MY_COINBASE_API_KEY"];
//$secret = $_SERVER["HTTP_MY_COINBASE_API_SECRET"];

// Set up CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'CoinbaseAPI');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER 
  , array ( "Authorization: Bearer " . $oauth_provided_access_token
         , "CB-VERSION:" . $API_VERSION
         , "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP:" . $timestamp    
         ) 
  );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );

$response = curl_exec($ch); // Actual account info

$info = curl_getinfo($ch); // Get more debugging info

curl_close($ch);

$response_object=json_decode($response);

echo $response_object->{"data")->{"id"}; // User Account ID
```